# How I can find out Activity percent from being idle time in c#?

Tags: c#

Here, I want to count the IdleTime.Seconds and store it in a variable say Count and then count all the IdleTime.Seconds  in a specific period of time. For example Let's say I have 45 seconds then 30 seconds of time from the slots of 60,60 seconds then I have to add the 45 and 30 which results 75/120 *100 so the activity level percent is 62% but I am facing the dynamic issues for the input here.

namespace
MyMonitor
{
class Program
{
static void Main()
{

```
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Last Input: {LastInput.ToShortTimeString()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Idle for: {IdleTime.Seconds} Seconds");
            Console.WriteLine($"Idle for: {IdleTime.Minutes} Minutes");
           // Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine(IdleTime.Minutes));

            if(IdleTime.Seconds < IdleTime.Minutes )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A Minutes over");
                if(IdleTime.Seconds < IdleTime.Minutes && IdleTime.Minutes > 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("2 minutes over");
                   
                }
                                    
            }
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
    private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref Lastinputinfo plii);
    private static readonly DateTime SystemStartup = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-Environment.TickCount);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct Lastinputinfo
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public readonly int dwTime;
    }

    public static DateTime LastInput => SystemStartup.AddMilliseconds(LastInputTicks);

    public static TimeSpan IdleTime => DateTime.Now.Subtract(LastInput);

    private static int LastInputTicks
    {
        get
        {
            var lii = new Lastinputinfo { cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Lastinputinfo)) };
            //TimeSpan timespent = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(LastInputTicks);
            GetLastInputInfo(ref lii);
            return lii.dwTime;
        }
    }
}
```

}